# google Endpoints on app-engine encoding UTF-8 doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8

im building a google endpoint in java that supports angular requests.
The items in datastore contain UTF-8 encoded data. 
While on the datastore local viewer i can see the data just fine,
after querying the items i see them on the following format: "×ª××× ×××ª×"

im using the following EntityManagerFactory:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

and i run the simple query:

```
returnList = mgr.createQuery("select from Content as Content").getResultList();
```

after running the following code:

```
ptext = c.getHeadline().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

i see the real values, which means that the encoding is wrong.

i've tried doing the following:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Or even on appengine-web.xml:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
```

but it didn't really work.

Does anyone have answer for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, because im using google Endpoints and i cannot deal with the HttpResponse there. as mentioned on that issue.

Comment: How are you getting the value of `c`?

Comment: c is one of the objects queried from the datastore.

Comment: Yes, I got that: how are you querying them from the datastore? Something must be wrong before the code you have posted, since you've already got the data.

Comment: Please add code to the question, not as a comment. What is `getEM()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner done. thanks for the help.